# Is there an equation for a function isSpaceChar in Java on Swift Character Class?

Tags: swift

Is there an equation for a function `isSpaceChar` like in Java on the class `Character` stdlib in Swift?

In Java this function is to get true or false from a value of AsciiValue character.

For example a character space `" "` the AsciiValue is 32.

Comment: Do you mean [`Character.isWhiteSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127019-iswhitespace) ?

Comment: @MartinR: No bro. Like this https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/78ccfd5f7e4880597fd90c61453a3be0e7aee5f0/sdk/sources/android-21/java/lang/Character.java on line 2968

Comment: @MartinR i think OP wants to know the expression that `Char.isWhiteSpace` will evaluate to decide whether it will return true or false.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: In Java function Character.isSpaceChar the paremeter in a Int which it is codepoint I have type AsciiValue, but in Swift Character.isWhiteSpace is for check all character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unicode properties for `Character` and `UnicodeScalar` were introduced with Swift 5, see

- [SE-0211 Add Unicode Properties to Unicode.Scalar](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0211-unicode-scalar-properties.md) and
- [SE-0221 Character Properties](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0221-character-properties.md)

In particular, [`Character.isWhiteSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127019-iswhitespace) respectively [`Unicode.Scalar.isWhiteSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/properties/3081607-iswhitespace)  is

> A Boolean value indicating whether this character represents whitespace, including newlines.

Example for characters:

```
let char: Character = " "
if char.isWhitespace {
    // ...
}
```

Example for Unicode scalar values:

```
let value = 32
if let uc = UnicodeScalar(value), uc.properties.isWhitespace  {
    // ...
}
```